# Show that $\theta^2$ is the identity if and only if $a = a^{p^2}$ for all $a \in k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime and let $k$ be a field with $p^2$ elements. Define $\theta: k \to k$ by $\theta(a) = a^p$ for all $a \in k$.

Show that $\theta^2$ is the identity if and only if $a = a^{p^2}$ for all $a \in k$.

Suppose $a = a^{p^2}$. I'm trying to show that $\theta(a)^2 = \theta(a)\theta(a) = a$. I found that $\theta(a^p) = (a^p)^p = a^{p^2} = a$, so I think I can show the above by finding that $\theta(a^p) = \theta(a)^2$, but I'm not sure how to get this.

Comment: $\theta^2(a) = \theta(a^{p}) = a^{p^2} = a$ for all $a$, so $a^{p^2} = a$ for all $a$ implies that $\theta^2$ is the identity. The other direction is very similar.

Comment: Why is the first equality true?

Comment: $\theta^2(a) = \theta(\theta(a)) = \theta(a^p)$. I am sorry, I think $\theta^2$ means composition and not the square, but you need to clarify this. If not, I will delete these comments.

Comment: Ah, ok. Can't believe I missed that, thanks! I too thought it was square, but that's exactly how it was written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\theta^2(a)=\theta(a^p)=a^{p^2}=a$ so $\theta^2$ is the identity. 
On the outer hand, if $\theta^2$ is the identity it holds that $\theta^2(a)=a$ and $\theta^2(a)=\theta(a^p)=a^{p^2}$ for all $a\in k$, so $a=a^{p^2}$.